# Which setting to make highcart scale more vertically?

Tags: css, highcharts

I use highchart on a webpage but under certain circumstances it scales a little bit odd. As you can see in the image the orange line "Total income" dissapperas at the top..

What I would like is to know some setting to change the scaling to make it show the whole orange line..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed0M0.jpg

Comment: Without seeing what code you have to create your chart all we can do is guess. Is your `yAxis` set with a min/max? Are you forcing a chart render height outside of available space?

Comment: There are numerous things you can do, but in the chart that you posted, it not "disappearing" -  you are positioning the legend inside the plot area, and it is hiding the series. Move the legend outside of the plot area, and it will work fine.

Comment: Thx guys, moving the legend a little bit by modifing the "y"-parameter did the trick.